# Should I REINDEX table after large update on column not concerned by the indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing

To speed up an update on a large postgresql table, I disable the indexes :

```sql
UPDATE pg_index SET indisready=false WHERE indrelid = ( SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname='mytable')
```

Then run my update :

```sql
update mytable set ......
```

Then enable my indexes :

```sql
UPDATE pg_index SET indisready=true WHERE indrelid = ( SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname='mytable');
```

Then reindex :

```sql
REINDEX table mytable;
```

Is the last reindex necessary considering that my update is about columns not concerned by my indexes ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recipe for data corruption.

It will only work if **all** your updates happen to be HOT updates, because only in that case the `ctid` of the row (the physical address which is referenced by the index) remains the same.

If you have to mess with the catalogs, then only disable those indexes that you are going to `REINDEX` later.  But it would be **much** better to just drop these indexes and create them again. That way you don't have to mess with the catalogs and run no risk of data corruption.

See [the source documentation](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT) for details about HOT.